# Find the closest sniffer for a tag according to RSSI value

Tags: bluetooth, rxjs

I have a scenario where I'm tracking bluetooth tags in a mesh network, and I want to know at any given point in time, which `nodeId` (sniffer) the tag is closest to (according to the `rssi` value).

Given a running window of data coming in:

```
{ mac: '123', nodeId: 1, rssi: 1 }
{ mac: '456', nodeId: 2, rssi: 3 }
```

My idea is I want to get fx the latest 3 readings from a mac, find the one with the highest `rssi` value, and output that and only if it changed the `nodeId` and `mac` from the last output. I have the code below which is almost there, but things starts to get messy when there are more than one mac address.

Can you point me in a direction? I guess I need to group by the Mac as well?

```js
const { from } = require('rxjs');
const {
  window,
  map,
  windowCount,
  mergeAll,
  max,
  distinctUntilKeyChanged,
  groupBy,
  mergeMap,
  toArray
} = require('rxjs/operators');

const source = from([
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 1, rssi: 1 },
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 2, rssi: 2 },
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 1, rssi: 4 },
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 1, rssi: 3 },
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 3, rssi: 2 },
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 1, rssi: 2 },
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 1, rssi: 8 },
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 2, rssi: 8 },
  { mac: '456', nodeId: 2, rssi: 10 },
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 2, rssi: 11 },
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 3, rssi: 9 },
  { mac: '456', nodeId: 3, rssi: 9 },
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 2, rssi: 11 },
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 3, rssi: 9 },
  { mac: '456', nodeId: 3, rssi: 9 },
  { mac: '123', nodeId: 3, rssi: 10 }
]);

const GROUP_BY = 'nodeId';
const COMPARE_KEY = 'rssi';
const WINDOW = 3;

const comparer = field => (a, b) => (a[field] < b[field] ? -1 : 1);

source
  .pipe(
    groupBy(metric => metric[GROUP_BY]),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
    mergeAll(),
    windowCount(WINDOW),
    map(metric => metric.pipe(max(comparer(COMPARE_KEY)))),
    mergeAll(),
    distinctUntilKeyChanged(COMPARE_KEY)
  )
  .subscribe(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

**EDIT**
@Dorus was amazing and got it all cleaned up, this seems to be doing the trick:

```js
const GROUP_BY = 'mac';
const COMPARE_KEY = 'rssi';
const BUFFER_SIZE = 3;
const DISTINCT_BY_FIELDS = ['nodeId', 'mac'];

const comparer = field => (a, b) => (a[field] < b[field] ? -1 : 1);
const distinctFieldsComparer = fields => (x, y) => fields.every(field => x[field] === y[field]);

source
  .pipe(
    groupBy(metric => metric[GROUP_BY]),
    mergeMap(group =>
      group.pipe(
        bufferCount(BUFFER_SIZE, 1),
        mergeMap(metric => from(metric).pipe(max(comparer(COMPARE_KEY)))),
        distinctUntilChanged(distinctFieldsComparer(DISTINCT_BY_FIELDS))
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is close, in fact i could reuse most of it.

What goes wrong is that `group.pipe(toArray())` will only emit when the group completes (and that only happens when the source completes). What you want to do is get a sliding window. You can do so using `bufferCount(BUFFER_SIZE, 1)`. It will emit the last 3 items every 1 item, thus allowing you to check the last 3 items every time the group gets a new item.

```
const GROUP_BY = 'mac';
const DISTINCT_BY = 'nodeId';
const COMPARE_KEY = 'rssi';
const distinctComparer = field => (x, y) => x[field] === y[field];
const BUFFER_SIZE = 3;
const comparer = field => (a, b) => (a[field] < b[field] ? -1 : 1);

source.pipe(
    groupBy(metric => metric[GROUP_BY])
    mergeMap(grp => grp.pipe(
      bufferCount(BUFFER_SIZE, 1)),
      mergeMap(metric => from(metric).pipe(max(comparer(COMPARE_KEY))))
      distinctUntilChanged(distinctComparer(DISTINCT_BY))
    )  
  )
```

Also i think you want to compare and get the max on the group. To do so you need to put everything inside the mergeMap that handles the individual groups.

Comment: amazing! thanks! I'll run it though some testing, but initially it seems very fine!

Comment: actually it's pretty perfect, the only thing missing was to compare BOTH `mac` and `rssi` for distinction. I edited my answer with the solution. 1000 thanks again!